# OpenCV applying filters to specific place in image

Tags: java, opencv, filtering

Hello I am using OpenCV for Java and want to blur faces from image, but I keep failing to apply it only for face. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use Haar cascade and build a classifier based on that

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too general. What basically needs to be done is to run a face detection algorithm (google for face detection opencv), extract the rectangle of pixels depicting the face using cv::rect, blur them and replace the original pixels. I suggest you read about face detection (try to understand the main ideas regardless of openCV), read some tutorials on implementation and then, if you need assistance, write a more specific question here and people are sure to answer you.